# Is there any method to log into blackberry 10 through usb cable

Tags: blackberry-10

Now I face a tricky problem. My Blackberry Classics has a black screen problem. When I connect it to my laptop with USB cable, Blackberry Link can detect it. However when it tried to connect to it, the Blackberry Blend prompted me to set the Allow Connections switch to on on the device. Obviously, I could not do that. I am thinking maybe there is a method to let me connect to the Blackberry 10 through the USB port just like a console port, but I am not sure. Does anyone know about it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would you like to do? You can use SSH through Momentics if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Momenitcs does provide a few ways to connect with a device. But generally the device has to be in development mode, which requires interacting with the device which you apparently can't do. The access is also limited to the development user so you could not use it to, for example, access data from installed applications.

About the only thing you can do at this point is use link to backup your data and restore to that phone once repaired, or to a new phone.

Also, since this question is not really suitable for StackOverflow I'm going to flag it for closing. Questions like this properly belong on SuperUser http://meta.superuser.com/questions/4836/what-is-the-difference-between-super-user-and-stack-overflow/4838